# Adding HTTP headers for security using .htaccess breaks images on WordPress site

Tags: wordpress, image, apache, .htaccess, http-headers

When I add this code in my .htaccess file. All my headers are secured but then my images are not working. After removing this code Images working perfectly.

Is there any suggestion for me to secure my WordPress website HTTP Headers?

```
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" env=HTTPS
    Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
    Header set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
    Header set X-Frame-Options DENY
    Header set Referrer-Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
    Header set Content-Security-Policy default-src 'self'; script-src 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' http:; style-src 'unsafe-inline' http:; img-src http: data:; font-src http: data:; sandbox allow-forms allow-scripts
    Header set Permissions-Policy 'self'
</ifModule>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding "image-src 'self'"?

Comment: Can you try setting the headers one at a time and see which one is causing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try the following? I have removed the `img-src http: data:;`

```
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" env=HTTPS
    Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
    Header set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
    Header set X-Frame-Options DENY
    Header set Referrer-Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
    Header set Content-Security-Policy default-src 'self'; script-src 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' http:; style-src 'unsafe-inline' http:; font-src http: data:; sandbox allow-forms allow-scripts
    Header set Permissions-Policy 'self'
</ifModule>
```